# java.net.SocketTimeoutException occurred after 1s~3s but my ok http timeout set 10s

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

My app is using Retrofit+okhttp.
Sometimes, it throw SocketTimeoutException just through
1s~3s after request but my okhttp timeout is setting 10s.
It's my code.

```
 private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(headerinterceptor)
            .build();

    return client;
}

public static XXXX XXXX() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(XXXX)
            .addConverterFactory(StatusProcessConverter.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(getClient())
            .build();

    XXXX methods = retrofit.create(XXXX.class);

    return methods;
}
```

Can anyone help me ... why the sockettimeout occur less than 10s...

Comment: Wow I also found this issue... The thing is if you are using battery saver and go to background it will always cause this issue...

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov, when you say `battery saver` are you referring to the laptop/desktop power mode or are refering to `power save mode` in Android Studio?